# Manage TCP ports remotely in Windows Server 2003

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm connecting to Windows Server 2003 and trying to set up MS SQL Server 2008. SQL Server requires port 1433 to be open, but when I click on the firewall settings, I get a message that ipnat.sys is being used by another program. I also read up on the Internet that if I stop the Routing and Remote Access Service, I'll be able to use Windows Firewall. My question is will I be still connected to the Server with Remote Desktop Client if I stop this service? And is there another way of opening ports? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure Routing and Remote Access is the service that you want to be restarting.  Check 'Windows Firewall' or 'Security Services' under services instead. 
Also ipnat.sys sounds like its more to do with NATing and RAS as opposed to Firewall, so 1433 wouldn't be closed but rather may require port mapping.

Let us know how things works out, good luck!

Comment: I managed to open the firewall settings by doing these:
1) Start; 2) Administrative Tools; 3) Routing and Remote Access; 4) Right click and disable something that has your computer name on it.

Comment: +1 for providing the steps you used to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will get disconnected when turning NAT on/off, but you will also probably be able to re-connect again after that.  Make sure that someone is nearby to rescue you in case you can't re-connect though.